# Docker-compose not finding docker-compose.yml, Filepermissions?

Tags: 18.04, permissions, docker

I just cloned a git-repository (https://github.com/mailcow/mailcow-dockerized)  and wanted to pull the docker images with

```
docker-compose pull
```

but `docker-compose` can't find the `docker-compose.yml`.

Here's the directory listing and `docker-compose` output:

```bsh
root@xxx:/opt/mailcow-dockerized# ll
total 132
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root  4096 Jun  1 12:52 ./
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  4096 Jun  1 12:48 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  3223 Jun  1 12:48 CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   954 Jun  1 12:48 CONTRIBUTING.md
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root  4096 Jun  1 12:48 data/
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 15111 Jun  1 12:48 docker-compose.yml
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    12 Jun  1 12:48 .env -> mailcow.conf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  7275 Jun  1 12:48 generate_config.sh*
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root  4096 Jun  1 12:48 .git/
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096 Jun  1 12:48 .github/
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   970 Jun  1 12:48 .gitignore
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Jun  1 12:48 helper-scripts/
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 35141 Jun  1 12:48 LICENSE
-rw------- 1 root root  4132 Jun  1 12:52 mailcow.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   992 Jun  1 12:48 README.md
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1746 Jun  1 12:48 .travis.yml
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 16845 Jun  1 12:48 update.sh*

root@xxx:/opt/mailcow-dockerized# docker-compose pull
ERROR:
Can't find a suitable configuration file in this directory or any
    parent. Are you in the right directory?

    Supported filenames: docker-compose.yml, docker-compose.yaml
```

I think I am missing something really obvious ...

Comment: I copied the folder to /root and tried it again and now its working ..

Comment: Same issue! I remounted my data to the home folder (also `/root`) and it worked. Do you know why this behaves this way? It's seems strange that containers have to be in a home folder to use docker compose.

Comment: I did not test it, but as far as I know, docker runs using the user and group "docker". If you try finding the docker-compose.yml outside of a home directory the docker daemon cant find the file, cause the owner is set to root. If you copy it to your home directory and (as a standard) your user is in group docker it will run, because you have sufficient permissions. so its no docker issue, but a file permission issue.